# Double INNER JOIN and SUM

Tags: mysqli, sum, inner-join

**Table pcKeyword**
kwId | keyword

**Table proPhrase**
kwId | vote

**Table contraPhrase**
kwId | vote

So the vote column is an integer and i want to sum it for the specified keyword
Something like this:

**exampleKeyword | 12 | 47**

Til now i have this but i doesnt work correctly:

```
    SELECT pcKeyword.kwId, pcKeyword.keyword, SUM( proPhrase.vote ) AS proVotes, SUM( contraPhrase.vote ) AS contraVotes
FROM pcKeyword
INNER JOIN proPhrase ON proPhrase.kwId = pcKeyword.kwId
INNER JOIN contraPhrase ON contraPhrase.kwId = proPhrase.kwId
GROUP BY pcKeyword.keyword ORDER BY pcKeyword.keyword ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT kwId, keyword, proVotes, contraVotes
FROM pcKeyword
INNER JOIN ( SELECT kwId pid, SUM( vote ) proVotes  
             FROM proPhrase GROUP BY kwId )  p ON pid = kwId
INNER JOIN ( SELECT kwId cid, SUM( vote ) contraVotes
             FROM contraPhrase GROUP BY kwId ) c ON cid = kwId
```

This way you do the grouping only once in their derived tables and not too often!
(By separating the tables into their derived tables I could also tidy up the whole syntax, since now the column names are unique within each derived table expression.)

See here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70634/1

**Edit**

Just for completeness, here the version with `LEFT JOIN`s and `COALESCE()` to make sure you get meaningful results for cases where there are no votes:

```
SELECT kwId, keyword, 
       COALESCE(proVotes,0) proVotes, 
       COALESCE(contraVotes,0) contraVotes
FROM pcKeyword
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT kwId pid, SUM( vote ) proVotes  
             FROM proPhrase GROUP BY kwId )  p ON pid = kwId
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT kwId cid, SUM( vote ) contraVotes
             FROM contraPhrase GROUP BY kwId ) c ON cid = kwId
```

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec51cb/1

Comment: this is not working :-( there is no column proVotes and no contraVotes

Comment: I made a mistake when pasting the whole lot together, sorry. See my edit now! Grrr, another edit, check again please ...

Comment: also not working i get thiss erroe: Unknown column 'proVotes' in 'field list'

Comment: Thx Man! it does work now. Any Idea for a good join Tutorial where i can read alittle bit?

Comment: I don't know, just play around and read the manuals or SO-posts when you're stuck. That is how I do it ... ;-)

Comment: I Just have one problem now with this query. it doesnt show the keywords without any votes? Any Idea why? EDIT it doesnt show the keywords if there is no proPhrase Vote OR no contraPhrase Vote

Comment: Just use `LEFT JOIN`s instead of the `INNER JOIN`s ... that is all!

Comment: I dobt get it work longer. it works for one day and now the query is just working in phpmyadmin and not longer in my script ;-(

Comment: @PunkRock Just edited my post again to include the case where no votes have been cast. Maybe the COALESCE() function makes a difference? Without it you would get `null` instead of `0` as a result which is "not a number" in PHP.